# Nginx & Symfony, 502 Bad gateway with some logins : character encoding issue?

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I have a problem with Nginx on an Ubuntu server and a REST Server made with Symfony. The Front-End is an app Ionic.

Here is my problem : Some logins didnt work on my REST Server.
bob@bob.bob or c@c.c is fine, whatever the password is.
admin@m2l.fr, or admin.m2l.org don't work at all :

```
> <html>
> <head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
> <body bgcolor="white">
> <center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
> <hr><center>nginx</center>
> </body>
> </html>
> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

The weird thing is, with the same DB and also same logins, i have no issue at all with XAMPP on my Windows... But i have a test tomorrow, and it'll be on Nginx :/

Comment: The weird thing is, how we suppose to help without any clue on how you check passwords?

Comment: Oh, it's a not secure at all way.

I send it with this route : http://adress/user/{mail}/{password}
It's not even crypted in the DB

Comment: I think my explanation wasn't clear enough, sorry.

If i put a user c@c.c / 123456 in the database, the login with those IDs will work. If i replace the password 123456 by azerty and i try it, it'll work too.
But, if i save a user admin@m2l.org / 123456 or admin@m2l.org / azerty, neither will work.

Comment: Put what and where? Nginx is working with urls, so what urls do you have and what config in nginx for them?

Comment: What are your logs saying?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the long wait !
I can't access to the nginx logs, i used the server of my school, and it's an other group's project :/
But i tried my website project on lan with `172.16.0.51/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/`
To login, the route used is a GET request to `172.16.0.51/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/user/{email}/{password}/`

And it seems the problem is when passwords contains numbers. But, to view a user's profil, the routing used is `172.16.0.51/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/user/{id}` and it doesnt trigger the problem. A friend of mine thinks it's a problem with numbers in second parameter. He's installing the same server on his own serv, so we can access to logs